# Querying a remote web API vs local MySQL DB during a traffic spike?

Tags: mysql, web-services

We're implementing some code on our homepage that depends on a geoip lookup for every unique vistor and we have a choice of querying a geoip web service (Maxmind) or downloading the database and querying it locally. The server is currently a 512MB Linode instance and only receives around 1500 uniques per day however we are concerned what will happen during a traffic spike.

It's clear to me that the local lookup would be faster but surely under load hitting the database would be a lot more ram/CPU intensive than processing an additional http request. Obviously upgrading the servers memory is easily achieved if going local is the best route.I would imagine that over a certain number of connections per second, the server would be more likely to become unavailable querying its local database than a web api (assuming of course that the web api servers can handle the http requests).

Any input on which solution would be the most robust long term solution to handle the occasional traffic flood without any denial of service would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Just to try quantify this a bit further, lets say the server would need to be able to handle up to 200 connections per second. Each connection requires a single DB query or http request.

Comment: Does anyone feel this is more suitable for serverfault? I wasn't sure where would fit best.

Comment: i wouldnt call network io over http a lightweight way to farm out work. id be suprised if it wasnt much more expensive than just looking it up locally. databases can be very very efficient.

Comment: But, if my server is not prepared to accept lots of traffic, do a local lookup will not be the very correct solution.

Comment: @GabrielSantos, you make the assumption that the non local lookup is less taxing on your server. I doubt it in most situations, especially if the server has decent ram. Network io is orders of magnitude slower than local io. This means each webserver thread/process just sits there, waiting for that slow network io to complete. The entire time, the memory and resources occupied by those webserver processes aren't servicing requests. That's congestion, and it will quickly overrun you.

Comment: Can you comment on how large  the database is and how often it changes?

Answer (score 1):

Given 200 hits per second you definitely want to go with a local database.  I doubt that  any third party website providing such a service would want to handle that many requests, but even if they did it's likely going to be much slower then local database access.

You will of course want to  increase the memory significantly on the local server. Keep in mind that memory is extremely cheap nowadays. For example, about 1 1/2 years ago I build a linux box with 32  gigs of RAM, and the latest CPU for under $1000.

200 hits per second may require a clustered database and multiple servers. You may also want to consider using a key value store for this, which can handle potentially thousands of hits per second.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out is to run a load test and see for yourself what performs best. But my gut feeling is that 200 queries per second is not overly much and can easily be handled in whatever way you prefer.

I'd lean towards using a local server with a gis database because local is cheaper (no costs per query) and a single server is easier to update. Also, you can scale up if needed by adding a second server or by configuring a 3rd party server.

I found some actual test numbers for this setup here:
http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/ 
This is a network setup where four clients query a single server. For a single client he reports 2000 queries / second and latencies below 1ms. Note that he uses the gis features builtin in mysql to reach these numbers. Also, this was 2007 so performance should be even better now.

Make your code modular and configurable. This depends on the programming language of course, but create a LookupService interface so that you can create different implementations if needed without changing the rest of the code. If the implementation calls a web service, make the endpoint easily configurable. If your service uses the same [URI scheme and response json as maxmind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/), you can switch at will from your own local server to maxmind and back again.

Answer (score 0):

Your provider charges their web-service by the query. According to the rates advertised on their website, at 200 q/s, you would pay... $72 per hour. You can get dozens of monster dedicated servers for this kind of money!

Comment: And further to goat's comment, at 200 q/s, the cost of having the database in memory becomes insignificant. Their CSV dump is about 200 MB, so it will definitely fit in memory. Queries are expected to be light and blazing fast due to the extreme simplicity of the database.

Comment: what if i have data of 200 gb and same data will be used for many sites , then which scenario is better , one master server providing api access or many mysql servers ? thanks

Comment: @AMB did you mean 200gb or  200mb

Comment: @danb 200 gb+ 25 mil+ records.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here. OP was comparing querying a third-party remote HTTP API vs. direct access to a self-hosted database. The decisive factor was the rate of q/s, the database size was irrelevant. We don't know enough about your requirement, but then you need to ask a new question. Please note, your question could be off-topic here. Consider asking at ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

At my work, we use a local version of the Maxmind database, which is a .dat file, and we query that file constantly (about 500 thousand times a day or more) without any problems. We then cache the information into a session so we don't have to query that information for the same user over and over again. We also have an Ad tool that uses the Maxmind database and then searches for ads that display within a 10, 25 or 50 mile radius of that user.

I would not recommend using the API for too many request or they may just cut you off without warning and now you have no Geo information. Also, if their servers go down you again have no Geo information.